# Can sanctuary and summon monster be abused to altar farm in a co-aligned temple?

Tags: nethack

Is there any problem with camping in a temple and repeatedly casting summon monster, then killing and sacrificing the monsters?  It seems like even a feeble wizard (especially one with a ring of slow digestion) could just keep summoning and killing monsters with impunity - possibly blocking the temple entrance with a boulder plus elbereth.

Does that work?

Comment: http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Sacrifice

Comment: "Sanctuary: A co-aligned temple" http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Sanctuary.  So the summoned monsters won't even attack you in this case. Until you start attacking them, presumably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep going for a very long time, repeatedly casting “summon monster” and sacrificing. Even without a ring of slow digestion, eating the odd summon will keep you fed. Beware only that you will occasionally summon a crowd which may involve strong monsters.

You'll need to re-read the spellbook every 20,000 turns. After 4 readings, the spellbook will fade, but you'll probably have obtained a magic marker as loot if you keep going that long.

Eventually, all the monsters that can be summoned at that level will be [extinct](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Extinctionism#How_to_make_creatures_extinct). Most species have 120 individuals, so you can keep going for a long time. It's quite possible to die of boredom (in real life) before reaching that point in the game. Paraphrasing [Jove](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rec.games.roguelike.nethack/OCzz8LD-n4I/xWFpI6QG9ygJ), the DevTeam has arranged an automatic and savage punishment for infinite summonning. It's called infinite summoning.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed summon and sacrifice quite a lot in a co-aligned temple. Even without knowing the spell, wands of create monster, bags of tricks and scrolls of create monster are very handy.

However, at some point, you'll get a giant who breaks the door or picks up the boulder you put there (note that Elbereth works only on hostile non-blind monsters); or a humber hulk who eats the walls; or a dwarf with a pick-axe breaks the wall from the outside. Once the door/wall is gone, monsters outside of the temple may see you and range-attack you: the sanctuary is effective only when the monster is *inside* the temple. The proverbial gnome with a wand of death may be the end of you.